# Outlook won't receive certain forwarded emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

The business that I work for has a website with an order form that, when submitted, sends the order information to the primary email (an address with the ISP, run through outlook) and a backup email (a gmail address). It has been working normally until recently.

It was brought to my attention when a couple of orders were missed from a particular client. Upon inspection, I found that the orders were received in the backup gmail account, but not in outlook. However, it was only the case with one particular client.

My boss needs the orders in outlook for organization, so I tried to forward it to the outlook account from gmail, and it never showed up. I then tried to copy and paste it into an outlook email and send it to itself, and I received a notification saying that it could not be sent because it had been marked as spam. I tried one more time pasting the contents of the email as plain text because I thought maybe the phone links might be setting it off, but I got the same notification of spam. I can forward the emails to other gmail accounts, but not to outlook.

We receive dozens of these orders a day, in the same format, with no issues from other clients, but in this case, and with two other clients since, we can't receive forwarded emails from them. Where should I be looking? What kind of things might set off the spam filter in this scenario?

Comment: You should ask your ISP. They probably have incoming mail spam filters in place.

Comment: There is often something you can add to put it in a safe list - for example, crude, but you could always include a code in the subject of the email - which is the 'keyword' to prevent it from being seen as spam

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm looking into it with the ISP. I think that it is most likely an error on their side, because we receive identical emails from other clients in the same email system many times per day without incident. ISP's being what they are however, it is a slightly laborious process, and any additional info is helpful in guiding them along.